# How to find status between dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have table like this:

```
Number  |Status     |Start_Date 
------------------------------------
A       |Active     |2016-11-29 22:51
A       |blocked    |2016-12-20 22:51
A       |Active     |2017-01-09 22:51
A       |blocked    |2017-01-29 22:51
```

My goal is when I declare date, to find  status on `A` number

For example:

```
Declare @Date varchar(25)='2017-01-10 12:40'
```

result:

```
Number  |Status     |Date 
------------------------------------
A       |Active     |2017-01-10 12:40
```

Because `2017-01-10 12:40` is between `2017-01-09 22:51` and  `2017-01-29 22:51`
then status is `Active`

But I don't know how to find status for Declare Date

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find the status for a single "Number" by doing:

```
select top 1 t.*
from likethis t
where t.date <= @date
order by t.date desc;
```

If you want to do this for all "Number"s, then you can use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by t.number order by t.date desc) as seqnum
      from likethis t
      where t.date <= @date
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to select the previous one:

```
select top 1 * from table
where Date <= @Date 
and Number = 'A' 
order by Date desc
```

This will then either give you a 'Active' or 'Blocked' status and its date.